# will the following cause deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading

Say the current thread holds a lock, then the same thread calls

```
synchronize(lock)
```

again, will deadlock happen?

I vaguely remember that the lock is re-entrant for the same thread, what does that mean?

Comment: How about googling a little bit?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html):

> Thread **cannot** acquire a lock owned by **another thread**. **But a
>   thread can acquire a lock that it already owns.** Allowing a thread to
>   acquire the same lock more than once enables reentrant
>   synchronization. This describes a situation where synchronized code,
>   directly or indirectly, invokes a method that also contains
>   synchronized code, and both sets of code use the same lock.

Answer (score 7):

You remember correctly, *reentrant* means that the same thread can obtain the same lock several times, e.g.:

```
private final Object lock = new Object();

public void foo() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        bar();
    }
}

public void bar() {
    synchronized(lock) {
        //...
    }
}
```

works as expected, as well as (here `this` is used as an implicit lock object):

```
public synchronized void foo() {
    bar();
}

public synchronized void bar() {
    //...
}
```

and no deadlocks occurs. Of course other threads can't access neither `foo()` nor `bar()` at the same time because the lock is already taken.

The bottom line: locks are take by threads, not by methods/blocks of code. And taking a lock already obtained by the same thread is a no-op.

Answer (score 0):

Every `object` has a `lock and a key` to protect its `crucial data state`, 
so does `every Class has a lock and a key` to protects its `crucial static data state.`

`synchronized keyword on the atomic statements` (either method or atomized statements)

will be like locking the object. When a thread access that method or atomic statement, 
it has to obtain the `key for that object`.

```
Once it obtains the key, 
its free to access this synchronized method/statement
or any other synchronized method/statement of that object.
Thats what reentrant is all about.
```

But no other thread will be able to access this object's synchornized blocks until current key holding thread, let go of the key.